# I want my content div to push my footer down?

Tags: html, css

I want my content div to push my footer down, so I can add as much text as I want. Unfortunately, my text is just overlapping my footer. What CSS code am I missing?

I know I can use `overflow: scroll;` but I want the webpage to expand vertically with how ever much text is on each page. Right now, I've got it set with `margin-top: 660px;` which restricts the rest of my pages. But `margin-top: auto;` isn't working. It's just pushing the footer up over top of my content div?

Thanks a lot.

JSFiddle Link: http://jsfiddle.net/davewebweb/n7ELh/

Comment: We need to see what you have to determine what you are missing.  Maybe a jsfiddle?  http://www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: Can you show us your code. Try posting it on jsfiddle.net.

Comment: @zsaat14 JINX Sorry...

Comment: @caffinatedmonkey Great minds think alike.

Comment: try posting only the relevant code. dumping your entire project isnt helpful.

Comment: y'all gave up on me? haha damn it

Comment: I'm not giving up yet but the fiddle dosent seem to make any sense. nothing is there.

Comment: literally nothing? i thought all my code was showing up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm trying to read your mind because you didn't post any code but I bet you need to add a to [clearfix](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/) to the content before your footer. If any of the content in your footer is floating, then it will "float over" your footer and not *push* it down. The code below will fix that.

Try adding this css and `.group` to the `content` div:

```
.group:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

ex:

```
<body>    
    <div class=".group">

    ... your content

    <\div>
<\body>
```

This is the best practice way to do it. You can add this class to any element that you're floating to solve similar issues in the future. Additionally the link above will tell you all you need to know about it.

Comment: didn't help. Little confused about the tag ".group:after"? Currently looking at the link

Comment: its a pseudo element. You probably havent run into them yet, but they're worth a look. An more basic way to clear floats would be to add  `clear: both;` and `float: none;` to the content div. ( you can add it as a wrapper class for all of your content ). The way I mentioned in my answer is ultimately better though.

Comment: I saw that there was a side bar in your site right? if you floated it, this may be your answer.

Comment: i've tried clear: both; float:none; in my content div. didn't seem to do anything...?

Comment: hold up, something just happened

Comment: i added this to my content div. it pushed the footer way down?
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;

Comment: It needs the :after element. try adding the group class and then add it your a div wrapping your content.

Comment: wait...so I change the div name to .group:after ? that's not working. explain it to me like I'm 3 years old. hah

Comment: @user3159385 added an example of what I mean.

Comment: No problem! I thought that's what it was. Do me a favor and accept my answer. Also read that article! it will help in the future.